# How to protect against sql injection when using SqlKata?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, dapper, sqlkata

I came across some unsafe SqlKata functions:

Example

```
public class TestRepository
{
    private readonly QueryFactory _queryFactory;

    public TestRepository(QueryFactory queryFactory)
    {
        _queryFactory = queryFactory;
    }

    public IList<TestResult> TestFunction(string value)
    {
        var query = _queryFactory.Query("MyTableName");
        query.Where("MyColumnName", value);
        return query.Get<TestResult>();
    }
}
```

and output:

```
--> output --> sqlkata query log
--> select * from MyTableName where MyColumnName = 'Select Id from Users where Nickname = ''Admin'''
```

I have to use SqlKata and asp.net core. 
I need a solution.

Comment: this already looks like its using parameters and everything is safe and fine: query.Where("MyColumnName", value);

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to avoid SQL Injection is using parametrized queries.

As it is says the SQLkata documentation in [this link](https://sqlkata.com/docs) it does use mostly parameters to build the SQL executed. In that same link there are some functions that do NOT use parameters.

Because there are more safe functions rather than unsafe functions, I am copy-pasting the functions names that [are documented](https://sqlkata.com/docs/where) to **not** use parameters in the documentation:

- WhereNull
- WhereTrue
- WhereFalse

As a side note, if you are working againt a database that has a profiler, you can monitor what actual SQL is executed in the database and check if parameters where used. That is useful when working with closed source code components. For example in SQL Server you have the [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler) and the SQL Server monitor (integrated in the SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: I have to take string parameter value from out. So I use where query for data.

Comment: Where seems fine according to the documentation, you could also check the [SQLKata source code](https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder) to make sure they use parameters properly if you are curious or you want to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

SqlKata by default is safe and protect you from SQL injection if you follow the recommendation.

a. Use the native method to build the query as suggested by @bradbury9

```cs
var name = "unsafe string value here";
query.Where("Name", name);
```

b. When using the Raw methods make sure you use the parameter placeholder

```cs
var name = "unsafe string value here";
query.WhereRaw("[Name] = ?", name);
```

c. and the most important one, is to avoid using the `SqlResult.ToString()` to execute your queries.

The provided example is totally safe since SqlKata use parameter binding technique, here the logger do some extra work by replacing the actual value by their placeholders to show you the final result.

Comment: "here the logger replace do some extra work to show you how the query is built"... Causing OP a false impression of an SQL Injection problem ;-)